# Reduplication and words form

Tags: particle-と, adverbs, reduplication

Does 態々 derived from 態と? And does 態と derived from waza 「業 」and case-marking particle 「と」?

Comment: So this is the fourth time you asked about those "reduplicated words". Forgive me to say this, but your questions lack context, have unspecific titles, are too short, and often based on some wrong (or at least little-known) assumption. Please use a specific title, explain why this question matters to you, and what you already know so far. わざと and わざわざ have totally different meanings in modern Japanese. Do you really need an academic-level evidence that one derived from the other?

Comment: Im sorry if my question lack context and not have a spesific titles. I really need that one derived from the other because im on my thesis about structure and meaning of japanese reduplication. I had searched わざわざ and わざと from dictionary.goo.ne.jp and ive found that わざと derived from わざ+と and has same meaning as わざわざ. In my  dictionary called 'kenji matsura', わざわざ and わざとhave same meaning so my conclusion is わざわざ derived from わざとand わざと derived from わざ and と. Honestly I still doubt about these reduplication things.

Answer (score 4):

**In modern Japanese**, わざわざ and わざと are different adverbs. わざわざ mainly means "to bother to do ～ (although it's not necessary); to take the trouble to do ～; all the way; specially", whereas わざと means "do ～ on purpose (knowing it's usually a bad thing to do it); intentionally for a reason". But わざわざ
sometimes means "intentionally", and in this case the two are interchangeable (e.g. "わざわざ/わざと聞こえるように悪口を言う").

**In archaic Japanese**, according to [a 古語辞典](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%8F%E3%81%96%E3%81%A8) and [this article](http://www.urayasu.meikai.ac.jp/japanese/meikainihongo/8/sasaki.pdf), わざと meant something closer to わざわざ in the sense of "to bother to do ～". This sense of わざと is obsolete now. However the word わざわざ(し) also existed in archaic Japanese and it meant "contrived; artificial". I could not find the direct source that describes when and how わざわざ was coined, but they are probably not in a simple "original-derived" relationship as you might expect. Both existed, but there was a large shift in meaning.

Comment: 「わざと」の意味・用法について（佐々木 文彦）は読みごたえのある素晴らしい文献だと思います。ご紹介いただきありがとうございます。

Comment: Ok i think I understand now. Thank you for your answer! ~